# What would be a good way of expressing "Es un placer haber sido de utilidad"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

#### English

How can I translate the phrase "Es un placer haber sido de utilidad" into English? What ways sound most natural?

"It's a pleasure to have been useful" sounds a little weird for me.

---

#### Español

¿Cómo puedo traducir la frase "Es un placer haber sido de utilidad" al inglés? ¿Qué traducciones suenan mas naturales?

"It's a pleasure to have been useful" me suena raro.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because está pidiendo ayuda sobre una traducción al inglés, no sobre el castellano

Comment: I'd say "pleased to be useful" or something similar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A good natural sounding translation, that still keeps close to the original diction and wording, would probably be:

> *It's been a pleasure to be of assistance.*

Other possibilities might include:

> - *I'm glad I could help.*
> - *I'm more than happy to have lent a hand.*

On top of this, in *formal* situations, it also very common so say `No, the pleasure is (all) mine.`

**Example:**

> **Mary:** *Thank you for helping me find my keys, sir.*
>
> **John:** *No, the pleasure is all mine.*